# How can I set empty value to TaxonomyField of Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy?

Tags: client-object-model, taxonomy

I has a ListItem with TaxonomyField which has some value in it (some term of course). This TaxonomyField is single value only. So now I want to set it to empty, just as it was from the beginning, but I can't find the way to do it. What I has tried so far:

```
listItem.ParseAndSetFieldValue(taxField.InternalName, String.Empty);
```

It doesn't throw any exception on ClientContext.Update(), but field value for listItems stays unchanged.

```
taxField.SetFieldValueByValue(listItem, new TaxonomyFieldValue());
```

This gives me "The method or operation is not implemented." Exception

```
listItem["taxField.InternalName"]=string.Empty;
```

This also runs without exceptions, but value stays the same. BTW do not use such approach, use ParseAndSetFieldValue instead.

So could anyone suggest something that would done a trick? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
taxField.ValidateSetValue(listItem, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, there are complicated solutions to same problem out there but this one is neat!

Answer (score 1):

This works in SharePoint online Powershell as well. This code clears the metadata field.

```
$companyField = $doclib.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($docLibCompanyIntName)
$doclib.Context.Load($companyField)
$doclib.Context.ExecuteQuery()

$txFieldCompany = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]).Invoke($doclib.Context, $companyField)             
$txFieldCompany.ValidateSetValue($item, $null)
```